# Apache POI - The excel file generated is not valid

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

The excel file generated by Apache POI is not valid.
Following is the code extract:

```
// write file
@Override
public File writeFile(final List<Place> places) {

    final File file = new File(filePath);
    
    try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        createHeaderRow(sheet);
        int rowCount = 1;
        for (Place aBook : places) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
            writeBook(aBook, row);
        }
        writeWorkbook(file, workbook);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}

private void writeWorkbook(final File file, Workbook workbook) {
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void writeBook(Place place, XSSFRow row) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue(place.getName());

    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(place.getPhone());

    cell = row.createCell(3);
    cell.setCellValue(place.getFormattedAddress());

    cell = row.createCell(4);
    cell.setCellValue(place.getUserRatingsTotal());

    cell = row.createCell(5);
    cell.setCellValue(place.getRating());

    cell = row.createCell(6);
    cell.setCellValue(place.getWebsite());

}

private void createHeaderRow(XSSFSheet sheet) {

    CellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    Font font = sheet.getWorkbook().createFont();
    font.setBold(true);
    font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);
    cellStyle.setFont(font);

    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

    XSSFCell cellName = row.createCell(1);
    cellName.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cellName.setCellValue("Name");

    XSSFCell cellPhone = row.createCell(2);
    cellPhone.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cellPhone.setCellValue("Phone Number");

    XSSFCell cellAddress = row.createCell(3);
    cellAddress.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cellAddress.setCellValue("Address");

    XSSFCell cellRatings = row.createCell(4);
    cellRatings.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cellRatings.setCellValue("Number of Ratings");

    XSSFCell cellRating = row.createCell(5);
    cellRating.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cellRating.setCellValue("Overall Rating");

    XSSFCell cellWebsite = row.createCell(6);
    cellWebsite.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cellWebsite.setCellValue("Wesbite");
}
```

The output file is invalid with content:

[image]

Content of the file in notepad++ :

```
'Advocate';'8888881888';'';'CbIJVVWlK60EDTkRVr1M5nyrY_U';'address';'134';'4.9'
```

I have two issues here:

1. Header is not added to the excel I have generated. What is missing for this part?
2. The file generated is invalid. Is there anything missing here?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with my own fabricated Place Class and data.
It may be that the field data content of your Place has special content.

Comment: What you show as "Content of the file in notepad++ :" cannot be the result of `workbook.write(outputStream)`. As `workbook` is a `XSSFWorkbook`, `workbook.write(outputStream)` always produces a file in Office Open XML format and not a semicolon separated text file. So the provided code does not fit to the problem description.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. A bad call to the method from my side. The code is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is ok. The issue has been while calling the excel generation. Bad call to the generation of csv.